# Non-breaking space inside textarea placeholder in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea, placeholder

I have this code in the controller:

```
$scope.TEXTAREA_PLACEHOLDER = "Some text.&nbsp;&nbspMore text";
```

And this in the template:

```
<textarea placeholder="{{ 'TEXTAREA_PLACEHOLDER' }}"></textarea>
```

even tried this filter:

```
angular.module('common')
    .filter('trustHtml', function ($sce) {
        return function(str) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(str);
        };
    });
```

With this template:

```
<textarea placeholder="{{ 'TEXTAREA_PLACEHOLDER' | trustHtml }}"></textarea>
```

**No matter what I do I always see the '&nbsp;' in the placeholder...**

Is there a way to fix that?? 10x :)

Comment: placeholder doesn't render html, just text. Get rid of the `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 5):

Try using the javascript non-breaking space escape sequence.  \u00A0

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately this doesn't work at the end of the line

Answer (score -1):

Try using `\n` for line-break.

```
$scope.TEXTAREA_PLACEHOLDER = "Some text. \n More text";
```

Comment: It should honor spaces, but probably just 1 after eachother. Where do you need to space?